# Can any number be present in a Fibonacci-like sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Can any natural number be expressed in an increasing series (whole numbers, greater than 2 elements) in which the next element is the sum of the previous two elements? If so, what is the proof and how does one find some of these elements (such as Binets formula for the original Fibonacci sequence)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number

Comment: @SimpleArt May you elaborate on the use of Lucas numbers to answer this question

Comment: Their definition is your Fibonacci-like sequence.

Comment: @SimpleArt Yes, but every natural number is not present in them

Comment: Depends how you want the question.  Take the below answer for example.

Comment: @DanyilBee I feel you find the following subjects interesting that maybe are related to your question.  1)[Complete sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_sequence). 2) [Fibonacci coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_coding). 3) [Zeckendorf's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 4):

The answer is trivially yes: Say you have the number $N$.  Then take the sequence
$$
A_0 = 1 \\
A_1 = N-1 \\
\forall k>1: A_k = A_{k-1}+A_{k-2}
$$

Then $A_2 = N$.